# Deploy Marketing Definitions Error "Rdb Taxonomy repositories do not support data export"

Tags: xdb, configuration, marketing-definitions

I have a site that has been upgraded from 7.5 to 8.1 and currently I'm on production deployment.

I used a new SQL reporting database and MongoDB collections.

I noticed that the campaigns hadn't been records if I accessed the Sitecore Analytics and checked the reports related to campaigns I can't see any data, In addition, the personalization rules based on campaigns are not working too.

I tried to redeploy marketing definitions from the control panel and I got the following error in log files:

```
ManagedPoolThread #11 2016:12:09 08:19:52 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
Nested Exception
Exception: System.NotImplementedException
Message: Rdb Taxonomy repositories do not support data export.
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Taxonomy.RdbTaxonomyRepository.GetAll(ID rootId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Taxonomy.Deployment.DeployManager.DeployAsync(ID rootId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Taxonomy.Deployment.DeployManager.Deploy(ID rootId)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marketing definitions, such as campaigns, are stored and retrieved by using repositories, which may use different storage types. There are three repository types that are shipped with Sitecore:

- **`item`** repositories—these work with definition items directly in the content tree. The default database used is `master`.
- **`rdb`** repositories use the Reporting database. The reason for this is that some server roles (like the Processing role) may not have direct access to the Master database.
- **`remote`** repositories are used in environments where the Sitecore instance doesn't have direct access to the Reporting database. To access marketing definitions, `remote` repositories will query web services hosted on a remote reporting server.

I believe that your server is currently misconfigured to use **`rdb`** repositories for everything. The default repository for reading data on a CM server should be **`item`**, not **`rdb`**. Deploying marketing definitions from RDB to RDB wouldn't even make sense. Which is why you're seeing the error.

Since the default repositories are **`item`**, your configuration must have been patched to change it to **`rdb`**. You can easily verify that by opening `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx` and finding the following node under `sitecore/marketingDefinitions`:

```
<sc.variable name="marketingDefinitions.repository" value="rdb" />
```

This node will also contain a `patch:source` attribute saying which .config file patched it.

There are several OOTB patch files that may have changed this variable:

- Sitecore.MarketingProcessingRole.config.disabled
- Sitecore.MarketingReportingRole.config.disabled
- Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Server.config.disabled

If any of these files are not disabled, disable them. This will switch the variable `marketingDefinitions.repository` back to using **`item`** as its value.

To prevent configuration mistakes in the future, make sure to follow the server role documentation to the letter:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configuring_servers

Comment: I enabled the file "Sitecore.MarketingProcessingRole.config.disabled" because I have one server for both CM and processing, it is true that it mention we should disable this file on CM but we should enable it on processing server.

Should I keep the file enabled and just update the value from rdb to item?

Comment: @MohammedSyam try that, yes. When mixing roles, you will need to make changes to those role-specific files.

Comment: @MohammedSyam what happend after you change the value from rdb to item ?